# Calculate $I = \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x) \, \log(1+x) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Question**

$$I = \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x) \, \log(1+x) \, dx$$

**My try**

$$
I = \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x) \, \log(1+x) \, dx \\
= \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x) \, \left(\log2 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n \, n} \, (x-1)^n \right) \, dx \\
= \log2 \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x) \, dx + \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x) \, \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n \, n} \, (x-1)^n \, dx \\
= \log2 \, (2\log2 - 2) + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n \, n} \int_{-1}^1 (x-1)^n \, \log(1-x) \, dx \right) \\
\overset{\begin{subarray}{c} t=1-x \\ dx=-dt \end{subarray}}{=}\, 2\log2 \, (\log2 - 1) + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n \, n} \int_{0}^2 (-t)^n \, \log{t} \, dt \right) \\
= 2\log2 \, (\log2 - 1) + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n \, n} \int_{0}^2 (-1)^n t^n \log{t} \, dt \right)
$$

Comment: Maybe using $\frac d{da}(x+1)^a|_0=\ln(x+1)$ and an euler-like integral would work?

Comment: Im guessing you're looking for an answer without the use of polylogarithms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an exotic solution using dilogarithm: Substituting $x = 2t-1$,

\begin{align*}
I
&= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \log(2-2t)\log(2t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{1} [\log(1-t)\log t + \log 2(\log t + \log(1-t)) + \log^2 2] \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \log(1-t)\log t \, \mathrm{d}t - 4\log 2 + 2\log^2 2.
\end{align*}

Now define $ \operatorname{Li}_2(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2} = - \int_{0}^{z} \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t $. Then by differentiating both sides, it is easy to verify that

$$ \zeta(2) - \log(1-t) \log t = \operatorname{Li}_2(t) + \operatorname{Li}_2(1-t) $$

holds for all $0 < t < 1$. From this, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \log(1-t)\log t \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \zeta(2) - 2 \int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{Li}_2(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \zeta(2) - 2 \left[ t \operatorname{Li}_2(t) \right]_{0}^{1} - 2 \int_{0}^{1} \log(1-t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= - \zeta(2) + 2.
\end{align*}

Combining altogether, we get

$$ \bbox[padding:5px; border:1px dotted navy; color:navy]{ I = 4 - 4\log 2 + 2\log^2 2 - 2\zeta(2) \approx -1.10155 } $$

Answer (score 7):

You may continue by noting that integration by parts with the choice $$u = \log t, \quad du = \frac{1}{t} \, dt, \quad dv = t^n \, dt, \quad v = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ yields
$$\int t^n \log t \, dt = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \log t - \frac{1}{n+1} \int t^n \, dt = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \left( -\frac{1}{n+1} + \log t \right) + C.$$
Thus
$$f(n) = \int_{t=0}^2 (-t)^n \log t \, dt = (-1)^n \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} \left( - \frac{1}{n+1} + \log 2 \right)$$
and the sum becomes
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n n} f(n) &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \log 2\right) \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \\
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)^2} - 2 \log 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \\
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right) - 2 \log 2 \\
&= 2(2 - \zeta(2)) - 2 \log 2.
\end{align}$$
Consequently, your integral is
$$\begin{align}
\int_{t=0}^1 \log(1-t)\log(1+t) \, dt &= 2 \log 2 (\log 2 - 1) + 4 - 2 \zeta(2) - 2 \log 2 \\
&= 4 - \frac{\pi^2}{3} + 2 \log 2 (\log 2 - 2) \approx -1.10155. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

From Sangchul Lee's answer, one has to evaluate
$$ I=\int_0^1\ln t\ln(1-t)dt. $$
It can be done just by using IBP:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^1\ln t\ln(1-t)dt\\
&=&-\int_0^1t\bigg(\frac1t\ln(1-t)-\frac1{1-t}\ln t\bigg)dt\\
&=&-\int_0^1\ln(1-t)dt+\int_0^1\frac{t}{1-t}\ln tdt\\
&=&-\int_0^1\ln(1-t)dt-\int_0^1\ln tdt+\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-t}\ln tdt\\
&=&2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 5):

$u=1+x$, then $1-x=1-(u-1)=2-u$

\begin{align}
\int^2_0\log(u)\log(2-u)\,du&=\int^2_0\log(u)\Big(\log(2)+\log\big(1-\frac{u}{2}\big)\Big)\,du\\
&=\log2\int^2_0\log u\,du+2\int^1_0\log(2u)\log(1-u)\,du\\
&=2\log^22-2\log2+2\log2\int^1_0\log(1-u)\,du+2\int^1_0\log(u)\log(1-u)\,du\\
&=\log^22-4\log2-2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1n\int^1_0\log(u)u^n\,du\\
&=2\log^22-4\log2+2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+1)^2}\\
&=2\log^2-4\log(2)+2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\frac1n -\frac{1}{n+1}- \frac{1}{(1 + n)^{2}}\Big)\\
&=2\log^22 -4\log2+2(2-\zeta(2))\approx -1.101551
\end{align}

Comment: İ saw this method too. But you wrote before. +1

Answer (score 4):

As Sangchul Lee did, by $x=2t-1$ substitution the problem reduces to showing that $$I=\int_0^1\ln t\ln(1-t)dt=2-\zeta(2).$$
By Feyman's trick, it is easily seen than
$$I=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}B(x,y)\vert_{x=1,y=1}$$
where $B(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ is the beta function.

Knowing that polylogarithm values $\psi(1)=-\gamma$, $\psi(2)=1-\gamma$ and $\psi^{(1)}(2)=\zeta(2)-1$, the rest is just a tedious derivative calculation.

There is even a [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457849/how-to-find-partial-derivatives-of-the-beta-function) about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an overkill approach.

Letting $\ell(x)=\log(1-x)\log(1+x)$, we notice that
$$\begin{align}
\log^2(1-x^2)=\left(\log(1-x)\color{red}{+}\log(1+x)\right)^2&=\log^2(1-x)+\log^2(1+x)\color{red}{+}2\ell(x)\\
\log^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\left(\log(1-x)\color{blue}{-}\log(1+x)\right)^2&=\log^2(1-x)+\log^2(1+x)\color{blue}{-}2\ell(x),
\end{align}$$
so that
$$J=\int_{-1}^{1}\log(1-x)\log(1+x)dx=\frac{1}{4}(U-V),\tag{1}$$
where
$$U=\int_{-1}^{1}\log^2(1-x^2)dx,\qquad V=\int_{-1}^1\log^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx.$$
We will evaluate $U$ and $V$ in order to evaluate $J$.

---

For $U$, use symmetry about the $y$-axis to get
$$U=\int_{-1}^{1}\log^2(1-x^2)dx=2\int_0^{1}\log^2(1-x^2)dx.$$
Then the substitution $x=\cos u$ gives
$$U=-2\int_{\pi/2}^0\log^2(1-\cos^2u)\sin u\,du=8\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin u\,\log^2\sin u\, du.$$
Recalling the neat identity
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(t)^\alpha\cos(t)^\beta dt=\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1+\alpha}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{1+\beta}{2})}{2\Gamma(1+\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2})},$$
we get
$$U=8\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\right)^2\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{1+\alpha}{2})}{2\Gamma(1+\tfrac{\alpha}{2})}\right]_{\alpha=1}=4\Gamma(\tfrac12)\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\right)^2\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1+\alpha}{2})}{\Gamma(1+\tfrac{\alpha}{2})}\right]_{\alpha=1}.$$
After a little bit of differentiating $\Gamma$-functions,
$$U=2\left[\left(\psi_0(1)-\psi_0(3/2)\right)^2+\psi_1(1)-\psi_1(3/2)\right],$$
where $$\psi_0(z)=\Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z),\qquad \psi_1(z)=\psi_0'(z)$$
are the digamma and trigamma functions. Using the special values
$$\begin{align}
\psi_0(1)&=-\gamma,\quad &\psi_0(3/2)&=2-\gamma-2\log2,\\
\psi_1(1)&=\pi^2/6,\quad &\psi_1(3/2)&=\pi^2/2-4,
\end{align}$$
we finally get
$$U=8(\log2-1)^2+8-\frac{2\pi^2}{3}.\tag2$$

---

For $V$, we use symmetry again to get
$$V=\int_{-1}^1\log^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx=2\int_{0}^1\log^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx.$$
Next, the substitution $t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ gives
$$V=4\int_0^1\frac{\log^2t}{(1+t)^2}dt.$$
Differentiation of the geometric series gives
$$\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)t^n,$$
so that
$$V=4\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)\int_0^1t^n\log^2t\,dt.$$
Next, notice that repeated differentiation of $$\int_0^1t^\alpha dt=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$$ gives
$$\int_0^1t^\alpha\log^2t\,dt=\frac{2}{(1+\alpha)^3},$$
so that
$$V=4\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}=-8\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\frac{2\pi^2}{3}.\tag3$$

---

At long last, combining equations $(1),(2),$ and $(3)$ gives
$$J=\frac{1}{4}(U-V)=2(\log2-1)^2+2-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\approx -1.101551.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. Making use of the symmetry, we get that:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} \log(1-x) \log(1+x) \, {\rm d}x &= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \log(1-x)\log(1+x)\, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &=2\int_{0}^{1} \log(1-x) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n} \, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &= 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{1} x^n \log \left ( 1-x \right ) \, {\rm d}x\\ 
 &= -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \mathcal{H}_{n+1}}{n\left ( n+1 \right )} \\ 
 &=-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \mathcal{H}_{n+1} \left [ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right ] \\ 
 &= -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \left [\frac{ \left ( \mathcal{H}_n+ \frac{1}{n+1} \right )}{n} - \frac{\mathcal{H}_{n+1}}{n+1} \right ] \\
 &= -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \mathcal{H}_n}{n} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \mathcal{H}_{n+1}}{n+1}\right ] \\
 &= -2\left [ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \mathcal{H}_n}{n} + \cancelto{2\log 2-1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \mathcal{H}_{n+1}}{n+1} \right ] \\
 &=-2 \left [ \left ( \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} - \frac{\log^2 2}{2} \right ) + \left ( 2 \log 2 -1 \right ) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_n}{n} \right ] \\
 &= -2 \left [ \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} - \frac{\log^2 2}{2} + \left ( 2 \log 2- 1 \right ) - \left (-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}+ \frac{\log^2 2}{2}  +1 \right ) \right ] \\
& = -2 \left ( \zeta(2) - \log^2 2 + 2 \log 2 -2 \right )
\end{align*}

where we used the results

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \mathcal{H}_n}{n} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} - \frac{\log^2 2}{2}&\\ 
\int_{0}^{1} x^n \log(1-x) \, {\rm d}x = -\frac{\mathcal{H}_{n+1}}{n+1} &
\end{align}

where $\mathcal{H}_n$ denotes the $n$ - th harmonic number.

Answer (score 0):

Let the proposed integral be $I$. Notice that
$$I = 2\int_0^1\log(1-x)\log(1+x)\,dx.$$
Integrating by parts yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
I & = & -2\int_0^1\log(1-x)\log(1+x)\,d(1-x)\\
& = & 2\int_0^1(1-x)\left(\frac{\log(1-x)}{1+ x} - \frac{\log(1+x)}{1- x}\right)\,dx\\
& = & 2\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{1+x}\,\log(1-x)\,dx - 2\int_0^1\log(1+x)\,dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is easy to see that
$$\int_0^1\log(1+x)\,dx = -1 + 2\log2.$$
Let $t = (1-x)/(1+x)$. Then
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{1+x}\,\log(1-x)\,dx = \int_0^1\frac{2t}{(1+t)^2}[\log2 + \log t - \log(1 + t)]\,dt.$$
In view of $d(1/(1 + t)) = - dt/(1+t)^{2}$, integrating by parts gives
$$\int_0^1\frac{2t}{(1+t)^2}\,dt = -1 +2\log2;$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{2t\log t}{(1+t)^2}\,dt = -\frac{\pi^2}{6} +2\log2;$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{2t\log(1+t)}{(1+t)^2}\,dt = -1 + \log2 + \log^22.$$
In summary, we find that
$$I = 4 -4\log2 + 2\log^22 - \frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
I&=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x)\,\log(1+x)\, dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x)\,\Big(\log2+\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n\,n}\,(x-1)^n\Big)\, dx\\
&=\log2\int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x)\,dx+\int_{-1}^1 \log(1-x)\,\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n\,n}\,(x-1)^n\, dx\\
&=\log2\,\big(2\log2-2\big)+\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n\,n}\int_{-1}^1(x-1)^n\, \log(1-x)\, dx\Big)\\
&\mathop{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=}\limits^{\begin{subarray}{c}
 {t\,=\,1-x}\\
 {dx\,=\,-dt} \\
 \end{subarray}}\,2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)+\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n\,n}\int_{0}^2(-t)^n\, \log{t}\, dt\Big)\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)+\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n\,n}\int_{0}^2(-1)^nt^n \log{t}\, dt\Big)\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{2^n\,n}\int_{0}^2t^n\log{t}\, dt\Big)\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{2^n\,n}\,\frac{2^{n+1}\,(\log2-1+n)}{(n+1)^2}\Big)\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-2\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{\log2-1+n\log2}{n\,(n+1)^2}\Big)
\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-2\,\big(\log2-1\big)\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\,(n+1)^2}+2\log2\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-2\,\big(\log2-1\big)\bigg(\cancelto{1}{\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\,(n+1)}}-\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg)+2\log2\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-2\,\big(\log2-1\big)\bigg(1+1-\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)+2\log2\bigg(-1+\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)\\
&=2\log2\,\big(\log2-1\big)-2\,\big(\log2-1\big)\Big(2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\Big)-2\log2\,\Big(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\Big)\\
 &=2\,\big(\log^22-2\log2+2\big)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\,.
 \end{align*}